# What is mms protocol and how do I enable it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What is mms protocol and how do I enable it?

Specific protocol is missing when I try play internet radio stream.

Comment: Does xmms play it?

Comment: I don't have seem to have xmms(they seem to have dropped it from Bionic Beaver) and similar player(Esperanza) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

mms is an old protocol from Microsoft used to stream audio/video: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server

VLC (https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) should still be able to open such streams.

Comment: VLC just gives stream of code and is unable to play the file.
https://pastebin.com/QQeuaQq3

Comment: I do not have an MMS streaming server to try but regarding https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/ you should be able to pass the URL directly as command line argument to VLC.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work.

Comment: mplayer (not mpv) also supports mms URLs. Give it a try. http://www.mplayerhq.hu/info.html

Comment: mplayer gives error when starting.